# Bootstrap : how to set resolution for mobile page

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Update: Sorry about not linking the code. I cannot show the actual preview, but I can link the code via JsFiddle. Link on the bottom...**

---

I have a site with bootstrap with the width set to 300px when the screen is on mobile,

```
@media screen and (max-width:991px)
{

}
```

Basically what I have is like this:

[image: The Display in mobile now]

But, what I want it to be is like this:

[image: Should Be]

How do I do this? I tried to set the container 300px, set the body and html to 300px. But still have some excess content in the sides. How do I fix this???

Link : http://jsfiddle.net/godheaper/hyfueqd5/3/

Comment: add some code please

Comment: Do show some the code which have you tried a fiddle may be more useful.

Comment: Try using `.container-fluid` instead of `.container`.

Comment: @BenFortune .container-fluid does not make a difference than .container. I tried